# how to remove keys of object inside with another object

Tags: javascript, typescript

i need to remove keys of the objects inside with another object using typescript.

```
let before = {
  '0': {
    'title':'title 1',
    'time':'12.30pm',
  },

  '1': {
    'title':'title 2',
    'time':'12.30pm',
  },

  '2': {
    'title':'title 3',
    'time':'12.30pm',
  },
}
```

expected results,

```
let after = [
  { 
    'title':'title 1',
    'time':'12.30pm',
  },

  {
    'title':'title 2',
    'time':'12.30pm',
  },

  {
    'title':'title 3',
    'time':'12.30pm',
  }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried using [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)? Basically just use that on the inner array and set the object to the returned result

Answer (score 6):

Just use `Object.values(before)`

```js
let before={0:{title:"title 1",time:"12.30pm"},1:{title:"title 2",time:"12.30pm"},2:{title:"title 3",time:"12.30pm"}};


console.log(Object.values(before));
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using `Object.entries` and `map`

1. Object entries returns array of object's key value pair
2. Using map return value

```js
let before = {
  '0': {
    'title':'title 1',
    'time':'12.30pm',
  },

  '1': {
    'title':'title 2',
    'time':'12.30pm',
  },

  '2': {
    'title':'title 3',
    'time':'12.30pm',
  },
}

console.log(Object.entries(before).map(v => v[1]))
```